Knapsack problem - reducing the number of decision variables
I am trying to solve something similar to a knapsack problem:
$$\max \sum v_{n}P_{n}$$
subject to some basic weight constraints. However, what makes this problem difficult to solve is that $P_{n}$ is a function of $x_{i,n}$, my decision variable.
$P_{n} = \sum c_{i}x_{i,n}/d_{n}$
In my problem, I have a portfolio of products that each have a price, $c_{i}$ and I can choose an amount of this product $x_{i,n}$ that I allocate to a customer, $n$. Note that there is an upper limit on how much I can allocate for each product. The constraints make this an interesting problem to solve (e.g., I need to allocate enough to satisfy the demand of each $n$).
$v_{n}$, $c_{i}$ and $d_{n}$ are all parameters. $x_{i,n}$ is a continuous decision variable.
However, I was wondering if there is a way for me to not use the $x_{i,n}$'s as my decision variable but instead use $P_{n}$ but with some constraints.
The reason I would like to do this is that I have a very large number of $x_{i}$'s. I was thinking something like an upper bound on $P_{n}$ could be the most expensive product in my portfolio and the lower bound could be the cheapest product in the portfolio. And I could add a constraint that says that the average of $P_{n}$ has to be the average price of the (weighted) portfolio. But the problem with this approach is that if a customer has a very high demand, I need to use multiple products and the price will be the weighted average price of all allocated products. So the upper bound is not necessarily the most expensive product, it depends on the demand of the customers.
I have not been able to find any literature on this kind of problem.
EDIT:
To add some additional context to my problem, here are the relevant constraints:
Each product,$i$, has a fixed amount, $k_{i}$:
$\sum_{n}x_{i,n} \leq k_{i}$
Each customer, $n$, has a demand that needs to be satisfied with the chosen products:
$\sum_{i}x_{i,n} = d_{n}$
To re-state my problem: Since I have a large number of products, I was wondering if there is a way to change my problem in a way that I do not need to consider $x_{i,n}$ as my decision variables but instead just use $P_{n}$, but of course with some additional constraints.

What are $v$, $P$, $x$, $c$, $d$? inputs, decisions? what do they represent?

$v$, $c$ and $d$ are parameters. $x$ is the decision variable and $P$ is simply a linear function of $x$.

Are your $x$ variables continuous, integer or binary? What does a typical "basic weight constraint" look like?

$x$ is continuous. And the weight constraints are e.g., the sum of products allocated to a customer must satisfy the customer's demand. So $\sum x_{i,n} = d_n$ where the sum is over the $i$'s.

So far the original problem seems to be separable -- the variables $x_{i,n}$ and $x_{j,m}$ with $m \neq n$ do not appear in the same constraint. Unless there is something tying the customer allocations together, you can solve a separate LP for each customer.

Because there is an upper limit to how much I can allocate of a certain product, does that not tie the customer allocations together? So $\sum x_{i,n} <= k$ when summing over all $n$ (where $k$ is the amount available of product $i$). Intuitively, if I allocate a large portion of an expensive product to one customer, I will have less of this product available to another customer, thus reducing his potential $P_{n}$.

@BenBernke, is it possible to show your math formulation?

@BenBernke Could you please edit your question to include these clarifications?

I have added the points from the comment section as well as the relevant constraints. Please let me know if there is something else I can clarify.

The problem seems trivial at the moment. All products can be used interchangeably to satisfy customer demand. Therefore, we can rank the products on price, and select the highest price products to satisfy demand. Then we observe each customer has a unique scaling factor v_n/d_n. We assign the most expensive products to the customer with the highest scaling factor, then assign the most expensive products that are left to the customer with second highest scaling factor etc. We can do no better than this assignment, which can be shown with a swapping argument.

@dijkstraa, you are absolutely correct. As I have specified the problem, your approach would work. However, I have left out some sensitive parts regarding $v_n$ because I thought this would not matter for my specific question. But essentially, $v_n$ is also a function of $P_n$. You can think of it as a churn function. So the higher the $P_n$ a customer gets, the more likely they are to churn. And then obviously I have a constraint that says I cannot lose too many customers. But for my question about how to go from $x_i$ to $P_n$, I thought this would not be relevant
